# Can not start containers while existing containers are in deletion

Tags: docker

I noticed that deleting running containers affects how fast new containers can be started. It seems docker start/run commands wait for the deletion process to complete before it starts/runs a container.

This behavior bothers me as we share our docker host with multiple people where container deletion could happen anytime when someone else try to run a new container.

Simplest way to observe this issue is to open 2 terminals, and delete containers while containers are starting at the same time.

- terminal 1: `watch -n 0.1 time docker run -itd alpine`
- terminal 2: `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`

Is there any way this behavior could be avoided?

I saw this issue on both `17.09.0-ce` and `18.09.1`.

Comment: I just tried `docker run -d alpine`, the speed won't affected by `docker rm`.

Comment: Containers to be removed need to be in running status at the time of deletion. The nature of the issue is that deletion of running containers affects new containers to run. Containers exit immediately if you just run alpine image with -d option.